# C# 9 records have { propertyName=value } output from ToString(), how to get from that, back to the record type?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Given

```
        public record SimpleRec(string PropertyName);

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            var simpleRecord = new SimpleRec("property");
            var recordString = simpleRecord.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(recordString);
        }
```

Output:

```
SimpleRec { PropertyName = property }
```

Is there an equally simple way to instantiate a `SimpleRec` from `recordString`?

I was hoping we wouldn't have to mess with XML or JSON serializers.

---

What puzzles me is that they chose the above string format for the conversion to string in the first place. If it had output Xml, JSON or even YAML, reversing the process would be fairly simple.

I think I want a generic fix for this. Maybe a conversion extension method, but then I need to figure out how to select on record types only. That or just use JSON serialize/deserialize and ignore the default baked-in ToString().

---

I tried this:

```
var converted = (SimpleRec)Convert.ChangeType(recordString, typeof(SimpleRec));
```

But threw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Use a regex or `String.Split` to extract `property`, then pass that into the `SimpleRec` constructor?

Comment: Or, assuming a public get; you can store simpleRecord.PropertyName as a string instead of simpleRecord.ToString()

Comment: Regex would be workable for SimpleRec, but not so much for more complicated record types (like records of records). It's just surprising to me that the ToString() output can't be easily converted back without writing some kind of parser.

Comment: @jwdonahue don't use `ToString()` for serialization. Use a proper serializer instead. Use eg `System.Text.Json` to convert to and from JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, ya I think that is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ToString` used here is not meant for programmatic use in this kind of parsing way - it is meant to be useful for debugging, and nothing more. If you need something deterministic: write your own `ToString`, or use a serializer of your choice.

Comment: The serializer seems to be the answer.  Thanks.